# Use of 'as' while writing about two events

Tags: phrase-meaning

I would love to have more clarity on the use of 'as' in the following sentence: 'Asia markets closed in the green as the dollar nursed losses after hitting 10-month lows.' Is 'as' used here to show cause-effect relationship or simply to state 2 events occurring at the same time

Comment: *Correction: cause-effect relationship

Comment: You can make corrections directly via the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: I turned on the radio **as** my favorite song began. Is there  any causation implied? There *may* be some connection, other than happening at the same time, but there is no need for such a connection, let alone one causing the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here I believe it is used to show concurrent events. As is not explicit enough to imply a causal relationship. Perhaps if the sentence instead used "because" or "as a result of" you could determine a relationship between the two. However, as is sometimes used to imply a causal relationship.

Comment: Here 'as' serves the function of 'while'.